# Infering instrinic product value from historical price-demand data

Tags: econometrics

This question is somewhat vague : Say we have 100 varieties of apples, each sold in exactly one of 100 marketplaces which are identical (in size, customer budgets, preferences etc) and independently operated, at potentially different price points.
We have gathered a table of average historical prices and demands for these 100 apples from these marketplaces and are planning to introduce the apples to a new marketplace (identical to the earlier ones), all at once, all at the same price. Can we make any useful predictions regarding relative demand for these apples in the new marketplace (assumptions can be made, if need be)? For e.g. can we predict which apple is going to sell the most?

Comment: You should add some details and clarity. Trivially if you assume both markets are exactly identical then the same price at market 1 as at market 2 gives you also same demands in both markets, you dont need to use an econometrics to  arrive at that prediction. The issue is most often to determined what the demand is to begin with.